# iphone-dev: Using variable from appDelegate in MapViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, ios5, mapkit

So in my appDelegate I have an array of events, like this:

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ListViewController.h"
#import "Event.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>


@implementation AppDelegate{
    NSMutableArray *events;

    /* for test data */
    NSMutableArray *titles;
}


@synthesize window = _window; ...
```

And I want to acces this events array in a viewcontroller like so:

MapViewController.m

```
#imports ...

...

-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [worldView addAnnotation:[ACCES_EVENTS_HERE objectAtIndex:int]; // <------

    NSLog(@"Loadded the view for MapViewController");
}
```

How do I do this?
And secondly, is there a better place to add the events on the map then viewDidLoaD?
(The events will come from a database so there will be lots of events)

Comment: What do you mean by loading from database? Will you receive them from some server/service in the internet? If so then have a look for asynchronous loading. That prevents the App from freezing while the data is loaded.

Comment: you should create a property and synthesize it in your appDelegate to access the data later.

Comment: It will come from a rest based server. And, if I create the property and synthesize it, the viewcontrollers will be able to acces it? I need only one such variable so it really isn't a property

Answer (score 1):

I think its a bad idea to store variables like this on the app delegate, but if you need access you can get a reference with

```
id<UIApplicationDelegate> myDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

you will need to cast this to your delegates class to access variables though

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but he would also need to make properties for his objects declared in the appDelegate, right?

Comment: either create properties, or implement setters and getters for the ivars he has shown above yes. i assumed that was done from the app delegate snippet above